# How to get application info from Windowsphone marketplace

Tags: php, html, windows-phone-8

I used to parse the windowsphone.com site pages for info about certain applications.
Today I noticed that Microsoft has stopped access to site - I receive the HTML:

```
 <div class="content-container"><fieldset><h2>Your request appears to be from an automated process.</h2>
  <h3>If this is incorrect, notify us by <a href="/static/redir.aspx">clicking here</a> to be redirected.</h3>
</div>
```

Does anyone know the proper way in web application (PHP) to obtain the information about app (especially it's icon), based on the app ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the API? It is just for search, but you can search by the app name and then filter the results according the app ID.

Example request: http://marketplaceedgeservice.windowsphone.com/v8/catalog/apps?os=8.0.10521.0&cc=CZ&lang=en-US&chunkSize=50&q=Pock8

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was missing

Comment: does it work for apps that are there only for windows 10 ? Like

Answer (score 1):

I found out that this also works and retrieves the web content:

```
            $agent= 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';
            $ch3 = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
            curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
            curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
            curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it from your WP application? If so you could simply use the `Marketplace detail task` to launch the Store or Marketplace.

Follow this one:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh394017(v=vs.105).aspx

Hope it helps!

Comment: Nope, it's my web application (PHP)